# Distance between highest and lowest point on rotated rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

I have a rectangle and I want to know the vertical distance between the highest point and the lowest point. The rectangle is 3×8 cm, and is rotated by $\theta$.

So for example in this picture I would need to know the length of the blue line (H, F):

[image]

Does anyone know a formula to calculate this?

Comment: You may want to go through my answer to this question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933508/find-the-rotation-of-the-object/3933539#3933539. It shows how to calculate the height and also how the height changes as we rotate.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the figure, the height is equal to $AG + BH$.

We have $AG = AB \cos \theta$ and $BH = BC \sin \theta$.

Comment: You might want to add some absolute values, to make sure that the distance in question never goes negative.